# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%'

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root'@'localhost';`

from a remote server to localhost/phpmyadmin but getting ERROR 1045 (28000): `Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: NO).`

```
mysql> show grants;
+----------------------------------+
| Grants for root@%                |
+----------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' |
+----------------------------------+
```

How can I resolve this problem? I have gone through a lot of suggestions over internet but can't actually figure out.

Comment: Did my solution work?

Comment: Rohit, this is what is happening to me
    `mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' with GRANT OPTION;`
    `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: NO)`

Comment: how are you looged into `mysql`?

Comment: `mysql -u root -h ip_of_machine`

Comment: There is something more. When I log  in using `mysql -u root -h localhost`

I get following error

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: then how are able to run `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' with GRANT OPTION` command ?

Comment: Oh, `mysql -u root -h ip_of_machine` this is working fine. But I mentioned the second thing because localhost should also work but it's not working weirdly.

Comment: seems like you have forgot password, try to reset it. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Yesss. It's working now. Thanks a lot sir!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you forgot to `flush privileges`.

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' with GRANT OPTION;
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Note:
I have included `with GRANT OPTION` because as doc says:

> The `GRANT OPTION` privilege enables you to give to other users or remove from other users those privileges that you yourself possess.

Edit 1:

Depending on comments, seems like you have forgotten the `root` password. So try to reset like this:

1. Stop the MySQL Server.

   `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`
2. Start the mysql without password

   `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`
3. Login to `mysql` as `root`:

   `mysql -u root`
4. Set new password to `root`

   `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('password') WHERE User='root';`
5. Flush privileges.

   `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
6. Finally, restart mysql normally.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root credential , then Set the privileges like mentioned below.

grant all privileges on db.* to user@'%' identified by 'pass';

Thanks